# Required attribute not Working in input tag

Tags: html, required

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sign-up-form">
      <style>
        body {
          background-image: url("background.jpg");
        }
      </style>
      <img src="./assets/user-Icon.png" alt="User Icon" />
      <h1>Sign Up Now</h1>
      <form action="/" method="GET">
        <input
          type="email"
          class="input-box"
          placeholder="Your E-Mail"
          required
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          class="input-box"
          placeholder="Your password"
          required
        />
        <p>
          <span
            ><input type="checkbox" name="Terms and Conditions" id="T&C"
          /></span>
          I agee to the Terms and Conditions
        </p>
        <a href="./home.html"
          ><button type="button" class="signup-btn">Sign Up</button></a
        >
        <!-- <hr>
            <p class="or">OR</p>
            <button type="button" class="twitter-btn">Log In with Twitter</button>
            <p>Do you have an account <a href="./login.html">Sign In</a></p> -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a sign up form but on clicking the sign up button it redirects me to the
home page even when the fields are empty...I tried using the required tag but it is not working too. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the submit button inside a link (`<a href="...">`). This link takes precedence over the button, when the user clicks in that area.

The button would not submit the form, either. For this it needs a `type` of `submit`:

```
<button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: but how can i change the target site for the button?

Comment: With the `action="target-url"` attribute of the surrounding `<form>` element, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 0):

Because you wraped your button in a link that redirect you to a different page,, you should use `<input type='submit' value='submit btn' />` to submit your form

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sign-up-form">
        <style>
            body {
              background-image: url('background.jpg');
            }
            </style>
        <img src="./assets/user-Icon.png" alt="User Icon">
        <h1>Sign Up Now</h1>
        <form action="/" method="GET">
            <input type="email" class="input-box" placeholder="Your E-Mail" required/>
            <input type="password" class="input-box" placeholder="Your password" required/>
            <p><span><input type="checkbox" name="Terms and Conditions" id="T&C"></span> I agee to the Terms and Conditions</p>
            <a href="./home.html">home link</a>
            
            <input type="submit" class="signup-btn" value='Sign Up' /> 
            <!-- <hr>
            <p class="or">OR</p>
            <button type="button" class="twitter-btn">Log In with Twitter</button>
            <p>Do you have an account <a href="./login.html">Sign In</a></p> -->
        </form> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You! But how can i change the target site on which the button itself redirects me?

Comment: add it in the `action="here"` in the form tag.